Why do we not define a pair as $(a,b) = \{\{a,0\}, \{b,1\}\}$ in set theory?
It seems like a much more intuitive way to define it, and you can easily prove it works using iff transitions:
$
\{\{a,0\}, \{b,1\}\} = \{\{c,0\}, \{d,1\}\} \\
\Leftrightarrow (\{a,0\} = \{c,0\} \wedge \{b,1\} = \{d,1\}) \vee (\{a,0\} = \{d,1\} \wedge \{b,1\} = \{c,0\}) \\
\Leftrightarrow (a = c \wedge b = d) \vee (a = 1 \wedge d = 0 \wedge b = 0 \wedge c = 1) \\
\Leftrightarrow (a = c \wedge b = d) \vee (a = c \wedge b = d \wedge a = 1 \wedge b = 0) \\
\Leftrightarrow (a = c \wedge b = d) \wedge (T \vee (a = 1 \wedge b = 0)) \\
\Leftrightarrow (a = c \wedge b = d) \vee T \\
\Leftrightarrow a = c \wedge b = d
$
So why would we not just use this definition?

That is Hausdorff's definition, isn't it?

It seems like how you determine $a$ and $b$ from $(a,b)$ is a little clearer - lest cases - when using the traditional definiton.

@AlexKruckman,ThomasAndrews Just a friendly reminder that answers in comments are not supported on this site. Also not for likely-duplicates. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1559/1650

This definition is not really that intuitive if you consider that $a$ and $b$ can be $0$ or $1$.

One advantage to using (x,y) = {{x},{x,y}} is that we only use the sets x,y in the definition.
It's a definition that doesn't require us to have defined, 0,1.
This is relevent when looking at arbitrary models, which may not have 0,1 as elements.
Let M be a class, satisfying the Union and Pairing Axioms
Then, If a,b are elements of M. Then (a,b) is an element of M.
So, M is closed under Ordered Pairs
This is not the case for your suggested definition.
It's often considered elegant, for a definition to be as minimalistic as possible.
